# iOS Swift stackview inside a scrollview with constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I'm still getting familiar with iOS and the use of `constraints`. Initally had my layout setup with some `constraints`. But I ran into an issue. When entering text, my `text fields` are covered by the keyboard. I found some Apple docs:  [Doc One](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), [Doc Two](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html) stating I should use a `scrollview`in this case. It sounded easy enough but every time I put the content in the `scrollview` things go nuts. I've tried adjust my `constraints` in several ways, but nothing seems to help.

Anyone have any insight on what I'm missing?
Thank you

Before adding the Scrollview[image]

After adding the Scrollview[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `UITableView` with static cells and make your view controller a subclass of `UITableViewController, you don't need to worry about the keyboard. The table view controller takes care of keeping the focussed text field visible above the keyboard:

[image: tableview demo]

I wrote **no** code for that demo. It's all done in the storyboard. Here's the storyboard outline:

[image: storyboard outline]

Comment: I actually tried this and it worked, but then shortly after I found this article [Scrollview and autolayout](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/) which was also worked out great.